# Purging SQL Tables from large DB?

Tags: sql, optimization, performance, database

The site I am working on as a student will be redesigned and released in the near future and I have been assigned the task of manually searching through every table in the DB the site uses to find tables we can consider for deletion. I'm doing the search through every HTML files source code in dreamweaver but I was hoping there is an automated way to check my work. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this is done in the business world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search through the code, you may find SQL that is never used, because the users never choose those options in the application.

Instead, I would suggest that you turn on auditing on the database and log what SQL is actually used. For example [in Oracle you would do it like this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107). Other major database servers have similar capabilities.

From the log data you can identify not only what tables are being used, but their frequency of use. If there are any tables in the schema that do not show up during a week of auditing, or show up only rarely, then you could investigate this in the code using text search tools.

Once you have candidate tables to remove from the database, and approval from your manager, then don't just drop the tables, create them again as an empty table, or put one dummy record in the table with mostly null values (or zero or blank) in the fields, except for name and descriptive fields where you can put something like "DELETED" "Report error DELE to support center", etc. That way, the application won't fail with a hard error, and you have a chance at finding out what users are doing when they end up with these unused tables.

Comment: Likewise, that will only give you what's been used since you started watching.  Better to assess the entire application & determine what will be done in the revamping.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse engineer the DB (Visio, Toad, etc...), document the structure and ask designers of the new site what they need -- then refactor.

Comment: Thank you. I can't vote you up because I "don't have enough reputation", but that's the approach I was looking for. I'm a beginner level programmer and I'm still familiarizing myself with the process of things.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by combing through the HTML source for keywords:

- SELECT
- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE

...using grep/etc.  None of these are HTML entities, and you can't reliably use table names because you could be dealing with views (assuming any exist in the system).  Then you have to pour over the statements themselves to determine what is being used.

If [hopefully] functions and/or stored procedures were used in the system, most DBs have a reference feature to check for dependencies.

This would be a good time to create a Design Document on a screen by screen basis, listing the attributes on screen & where the value(s) come from in the database at the table.column level.

Compile your list of tables used, and compare to what's actually in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the table names are specified in the HTML source (and if that's the only place they are ever specified!), you can do a Search in Files for the name of each table in the DB.  If there are a lot of tables, consider using a tool like grep and creating a script that runs grep against the source code base (HTML files plus any others that can reference the table by name) for each table name.

Having said that, I would still follow Damir's advice and take a list of deletion candidates to the data designers for validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have any tests in place around the data access or the UI, so there's no way to verify what is and isn't used.  Provided that the data access is consistent, scripting will be your best bet.  Have it search out the tables/views/stored procedures that are being called and dump those to a file to analyze further.  That will at least give you a list of everything that is actually called from some place.  As for if those pages are actually used anywhere, that's another story.

Once you have the list of the database elements that are being called, compare that with a list of the user-defined elements that are in the database.  That will give you the ones that could potentially be deleted.

All that being said, if the site is being redesigned then a fresh database schema may actually be a better approach.  It's usually less intensive to start fresh and import the old data than it is to find dead tables and fields.